# The reason behind choosing a particular version of Eclipse for Android development?

Tags: android, eclipse

The Android [website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) says - "We recommend the "Eclipse Classic" version. Otherwise, you should use a Java or RCP version of Eclipse."

But the book "Hello Android" (3 edition) says Eclipse Classic is not enough. Get Eclipse for Java Developers instead.

I always use the official documentation. BUT, I want to know -

Which version of Eclipse is good for Android development and WHY (THE WHY IS IMPORTANT) ?

Comment: Referred by android documentation is a good one always, they knows all time which is good for the particular development...

Comment: The document tells me which version to use. Thats fine. But why do I use the version mentioned in the android documentation ? Why ?

Comment: Fine. That is a recommended one in the document not a mandatory. Thats based on our wish, familiarity, comfort in using IDE's. 

But the developers of sdk , they knows perfectly, with which IDE the sdk will responds perfectly. Thats y the recommended IDE comes to point...

Comment: Let I say, I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers  
Version: Indigo Service Release 2, and it works perfectly for me, but the why or how, I don't know. I followed a tutorial on youtube to set this up.

Comment: @Bigflow - Then why not use Java EE version instead. I have argued that in the answer below. Please see it.

Comment: Who gave me a down vote ? Where is the justification for the down vote ? This place is frequented by a bunch of sissies !

Comment: To be honest, I don't know really. I started with this one (for school) and I have everything what I need. I am not going to install another version (don't fix what isn't broke). But Java EE looks good for development indeed.  

And about the downvotes, (for other people) please explain your downvote! People are here to learn. (upvoted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Eclipse you get [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) and other developer tools that are built for android. It's also open source and you get lots of cool plugins to go with eclipse. Apart from that, there is really no reason to specifically recommend eclipse. It's a good IDE but there are others too such as [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) etc.

It's a matter of preference really. You can even skip all the IDE's and go command line if you're feeling like it :-)

Among different versions of eclipse, there are many differences. Here is the comparision page from eclipse that details these differences:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php

Eclipse for Java comes pre-included with EGit, MyLyn, XML tools etc which are useful in android development if plan to use them.

Comment: I did not ask which IDE to use. Please read the question again.

Comment: answer updated. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, that was helpful. Can you give me a list of all the tools/plugins that are needed for Android development ? BTW, as per the chart, I think we could use Java EE version also for Android, right ?

Comment: All you need is Eclipse classic and ADT Plugin in my opinion if you are just starting out. You will learn and discover more tools as you go along. Don't worry too much about the tools. Just get the basics and begin development!

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between those different download packages is which plugins/features are pre-installed (and therefore cannot be uninstalled). If you then install ADT in any of them, the installation manager will assure that all the missing prerequisite plugins (like Java Development Tools and Web Service Tools) are added automatically. That means, *any* is good for Android Development, they only differ in the "bonus" plugins already installed.

So you can also download the much smaller Eclipse runtime binary for your platform, point it to the ADT installation and let it run. That will produce the smallest possible selection of necessary plugins for ADT being installed in Eclipse.

The only really important case for making a difference between the download packages is if you have to install it on a machine without Internet connection, because obviously the installation manager cannot download the additional prerequisite plugins then.